# Why kill is not working for some processes but working for others?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, kill, kill-process

I have created a C program that forks to create a few child processes, which also forks to create their children. They all sleep for 3 seconds and then terminates.
After running the program, I have paused it using cntl+z.

And the process hierarchy is like below.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ pstree -p 5955
sample(5955)─┬─sample(5956)─┬─sample(5957)───sample(5959)
             │              └─sample(5960)
             └─sample(5958)───sample(5961)
```

Now I am trying to kill all -

```
kill 5956 5958 5957 5960 5961 5959

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ pstree -p 5955
sample(5955)─┬─sample(5956)
             └─sample(5958)
```

Can someone suggest why the first two children (5956, 5958) are not getting terminated?

Ref: output from the program (sample.c) when I paused it :

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ./sample
parent PID=5955
Child=5956
Child=5957
Child=5958
Child=5959
Child=5960
end 5959
Child=5961
^Z
[3]+  Stopped                 ./sample
```

Comment: It's difficult to say without more detail, but I suspect they are terminated and are zombies.  All of their children have been waited on by init, but your main process is not waiting on them, so they are stuck in zombie state.